# bash: string variable contains asterisk. how to use this variable for searching etc with grep, sed?

Tags: bash, zsh, variable, string

Have a nice day
I have got text file (zz.txt):

```
Chemical name
3-Aminopropane-1-sulphonic acid
Synonym(s)
--
Homotaurine * Tramiprosate
--
Chemical name
Common name and synonyms
...
```

I have variable
s="Homotaurine * Tramiprosate";
I try to (un)select text of this variable from text file:

```
s="Homotaurine * Tramiprosate"; cat zz.txt | grep -i "$s"
```

```
s="Homotaurine * Tramiprosate";cat zz.txt | sed -ne "/$s/p"
```

Does not work.
But if I change $s to, for instance, "Chemical name", everything ok, grep and sed work correctly and similarly.
Variable $s received from another text file. Next time it could contain asterisk or not.
Yes I realize that asterisk is very special character. How can I solve my task with sed/grep?
And additional question - what others similar characters could create headache?

Comment: this is not a regular expression as understood by these tools, so in that mode, they are not what you need, unless you're searching for lines that contain `Homotaurine`, follow by two or more spaces (and nothing else), followed by `Tramiprosate`. I don't think that's the case. What *do* you want to find? It's sadly not clear to me.

Comment: For grep, you can use `-F` to use fixed strings instead of regexes. For sed, it's much more complex. I'd probably switch to Perl which can help you with its [quotemeta](https://perldoc.pl/functions/quotemeta) function.

Comment: I just want to write command cat zz.txt | grep/sed/... "$s" and see output "Homotaurine * Tramiprosate"

Comment: choroba, it that I want to get! hurraaa!!!! thank you!

Comment: Try `s="Homotaurine \* Tramiprosate";cat zz.txt | sed -ne "/$s/p"`

Comment: I could not edit variable $s. I read $s from another file, changing "*"  to "\*" if necessary is not good solution (by the way, how to do this without perl, awk, c etc?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For grep, you can use `-F` to use fixed strings instead of regexes. For sed, it's much more complex. I'd probably switch to Perl which can help you with its `\Q`/[quotemeta](https://perldoc.pl/functions/quotemeta) function.

```
#!/bin/bash
s="Homotaurine * Tramiprosate"; grep -Fi -- "$s" zz.txt
s="Homotaurine * Tramiprosate"; s=$s perl -ne 'print if /\Q$ENV{s}/' -- zz.txt
```

Comment: choroba, thank you very much. as I heard perl is powerful tool but for me grep/sed/tr/cat/sort is more than enough. it is more or less understandable for me.

Comment: If you want to match a fixed substring with Perl, you might also choose to use `index()`  (just like in `awk`).  I also notice that the user in the question may want to use `-x` with `grep`, unless their query string is supposed to be used as a substring.